# I can't center ul

Tags: html, css

I can't center `ul` which is a menu. I've tried `margin: 0 auto;` and `text-align: center;` and tried to change value of `margin` but nothing works.

**This is my CSS:**

```
html {
font-family: 'Exo';}

body {
background: #1a1a1a;}

.nav {
margin-left: 50%;}

.nav li {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
margin-left: 10px;
border: 3px solid #2E9FFF;
text-align: center;
width: 225px;
background-color: DodgerBlue;
font-size: 200%;
transition: ease 0.5s;
text-decoration: none;}

.nav li:hover {
cursor: pointer;
border: 3px solid #2E9FFF;
border-radius: 50px;
background-color: #1a1a1a;}

.nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;}
```

**This is my HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Najdi si hru</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Jaký je náš cíl?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can get started.

Make sure you zero out the padding on `ul.nav` and apply `text-align: center` to keep the inline blocks centered.

Note that for demonstration purposes, I made the widths and font size smaller, but you get the general idea.

If the elements are wide enough, they will wrap onto a second line.

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Exo';
}
body {
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
.nav {
  margin-left: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #2E9FFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  font-size: 100%;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #2E9FFF;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Najdi si hru</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Jaký je náš cíl?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok that works thanks and what if i want to move it to the right?

Comment: Do you mean add a left margin? See modified snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.nav {/*margin-left: 50%;*/ min-width:20%; display:table; margin:0 auto; padding:0}
```